# gdb cannot access memory at value-type variable

Tags: c++, assembly, memory, gdb

When trying to debug a core thrown by a seg-fault, the line it crashes doesn't really make sense in my eyes; there are two integers compared and the result is stored in a bool. This is the not simplified code:

```
bool doLog = level >= debugLevel;
```

This is the assembly-code where it crashes:

```
cmp    %ebx,0x14(%rbp)
  // ebx = 3
  // rbp = 0x6e696c7265
```

However when trying to print the value of the address stored in rbp I get a gdb error: "cannot access memory at address 0x6e696c7279"

What bugs me is that when printing the address of debugLevel I'll get a different address then what is stored in the rbp register used for cmp:

```
p &debugLevel => 0x6e696c7279
i r rbp       => 0x6e696c7265
```

Comment: Note that the instruction compares the contents of `ebx` with the value at an *offset* of `0x14` bytes from `0x6e696c7265`. That is, `0x6e696c7265 + 0x14` which happens to be `0x6e696c7279`.

Comment: Didn't knew that, thank you. Still I don't really get the "cannot access memory at" error. debugLevel is a class-variable.

Comment: As for the crash, an odd address of an object or structure is highly suspicious. The problem is probably not on the line where the actual crash happens but higher up in the call-stack. But since you don't provide more context or any kind of [mcve] we really can't help you more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**`0x6e696c7265` looks like ASCII codes for letters**.  You probably overwrote a pointer with string bytes.

(e.g. maybe a buffer overflow stepped on a saved RBP value, and then the function returned to its caller after restoring RBP, breaking access to locals when the caller tries to use RBP as a frame pointer.  Actually, `RBP+14` wouldn't be a frame pointer, unless maybe this is on Windows and the compiler allocated that local in the shadow space above the return address.)

> printing the address of debugLevel I'll get a different address then what is stored in the rbp register used for cmp

GDB knows from debug info that `&debugLevel` = RBP+0x14.

That's why the `cmp` instruction uses an addressing mode with a displacement of `0x14`, specifically `0x14(%rbp)`.  So of calculating `&debugLevel` from a corrupted base address will give you another bad address.

`0x6e696c7279 - 0x6e696c7265 = 0x14 = 20`.  This part is not interesting or related to your memory-corruption bug.